# C++, эквивалентность не существующего элемента массива и 0

Tags: c++, массивы, сравнение, логические-выражения

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename type_1, typename type_2>
bool equal(type_1 const &x, type_2 const &y) {
    return (x == y) && (typeid(x) == typeid(y));
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = {5};
    cout << equal(a[9], 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему несуществующий элемент массива равно 0-ю? Я знаю, что `false == 0`, но нет ли ни одного способа их различить, чтоб вышеуказанный код вернул `false`? Спасибо!

Comment: Что значит - несуществующий? Вы при инициализации заказали массив из 10 элементов - 5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 - так что `a[9]` - действительно 0. Если вы о том, что cout выводит false как 0 - добавьте нужный флаг: `cout << boolalpha << equal....` Словом, сформулируйте вопрос поточнее.

Comment: Ааа, понял , когда пишу например `int a[10] = {5};` получается  `int a[10] = {5, 0, 0,...}` а когда пишу `int a[10];` получаю массив элементы которого содержат разные цифры (мусор), Спасибо

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ,  с высказанием в скобках согласен, но  сне согласен, что и там и там это определение. Что считается определением, говорить долго, поэтому убрал свой комментарий, дабы избежать разворачиваний комментариями...